# Não consigo fazer include

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, controller

Tento fazer include, mas aparece a mensagem :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Em algumas das pesquisas que fiz dizem para incluir `using System.Linq;` `using System.Data.Entity;` mas o meu já contém estes.

Minhas classes são:

FotoAparelho:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MeuProjeto.Models
{
    public class FotoAparelho
    {
        [Key]
        public int FotoAparelhoID { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("URL")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Insira o link da imagem")]
        public string URL { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Descrição")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Descrição da Link")]
        public string Descricao { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Aparelho")]
        public int AparelhoID { get; set; }
        public virtual Aparelho Aparelho { get; set; }//Um aparelho
    }
}
```

E do Aparelho:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MeuProjeto.Models
{
    public class Aparelho
    {
        [Key]
        public int AparelhoID { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Nome")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha Nome")]
        [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "O nome do aparelho deve ter de 3 a 255 caracteres")]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Descrição")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha a descrição do curso")]
        public string Descricao { get; set; }

        //Relacionamentos
        public virtual ICollection<FotoAparelho> Fotos { get; set; }
    }
}
```

preciso fazer o seguinte: `var aparelhos = db.Aparelhos.Incluce(c => c.Fotos);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neste caso voce pode seguir 2 linhas:

```
var aparelhos = from ap in db.Aparelhos.Include("Fotos")
            select ap;
```

Para fazer desta forma que necessita você precisa do namespace Data.Entity.

```
using System.Data.Entity;

var aparelhos = from ap in db.Aparelhos.Include(c => c.Fotos)
            select ap;
```

Comment: Pra mim resolveu apenas colocando o `using System.Data.Entity;`